# Prooving $\mathbb{I}_{\{A \Delta B \}}=(\mathbb{I}_{\{ A\}}-\mathbb{I}_{\{ B\}})^2$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $A$ and $B$ be two events from $\Omega, \mathcal{P}(\Omega),\mathbb{P})$. I need to show that next equal is true $$\mathbb{I}_{\{A \Delta B \}}=(\mathbb{I}_{\{ A\}}-\mathbb{I}_{\{ B\}})^2$$.

I think $A \Delta B=(A\cap \overline{B})\cup(B\cap \overline{A})$ Is it right? what to do next?

Comment: Notation $\mathbb I_{\{A\}}$ is kind of confusing. It might denote the indicator function of set $A$ but also of the singleton set $\{A\}$.

Comment: Your thinking about $A\Delta B$ is correct, provided that $\overline A$ denotes the complement of $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My notation for your $\mathbb I_{\{A\}}$ is $\mathbf1_A$.

---

Since indicator functions only take values in $\{0,1\}$ for any $\omega\in \Omega$ the following statements are evidently equivalent:

- (1) $(\mathbf1_A-\mathbf1_B)^2(\omega)=1$
- (2) $(\mathbf1_A(\omega)-\mathbf1_B(\omega))^2=1$
- (3) $[\mathbf1_A(\omega)=1\wedge\mathbf1_B(\omega)=0]\vee[\mathbf1_A(\omega)=0\wedge\mathbf1_B(\omega)=1]$
- (4) $[\omega\in A\wedge \omega\in B^{\complement}]\vee[\omega\in A^{\complement}\wedge \omega\in B]$
- (5) $\omega\in (A\cap B^{\complement})\cup(A^{\complement}\cap B)=A\Delta B$

This proves that $(\mathbf1_A-\mathbf1_B)^2$ serves as indicator function of set $A\Delta B$.

Comment: Can you explain me step by step?

Comment: I gave the bullets a number. It is asserted that $(1)\iff(2)$, $(2)\iff(3)$, $(3)\iff(4)$ and $(4)\iff(5)$. Which of them needs a further explanation? If everything is clear then we have the statement that $(1)\iff(5)$, which is exactly the statement that must be proved.