# Proving $\mathbb{I}_{\{A \cup B \}}=\mathbb{I}_{\{ A\}}+\mathbb{I}_{\{ B\}}-\mathbb{I}_{\{A \cap B \}}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two events from $(\Omega, \mathcal{P}(\Omega),\mathbb{P})$. I need to show that next equal is true
 $$\mathbb{I}_{\{A \cup B \}}=\mathbb{I}_{\{ A\}}+\mathbb{I}_{\{ B\}}-\mathbb{I}_{\{A \cap B \}}.$$

Here $\mathbb{I}$ is an indicator.

So it looks like $\mathbb{P} (A\cup B)=\mathbb{P}(A)+ \mathbb{P}(B)-\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)$. But how to use it here?

Comment: Take any point $\omega$ and consider the cases where the point is one, both or none of the sets $A,B$. Verify the equation in each case.

Comment: Use the same strategy applied in the answer to this [former question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3031209/75923). Did you try? If so, then where did you get stuck? If not so then why didn't you?

Comment: I tied to understand that example. But accually I didn't. So I found another one example. Thought this one is easier and maybe I can understand this one.  I trying to understand this theory. I am not a student and everything what I am doing is only for myself. I want to know all this theory, because I will need this in the future :) So I really appreciate for your help and understanding

Comment: You can accept an answer by pressing the check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to show
$$\left(1_{A\cup B}+1_{A\cap B}\right)(\omega)=\left(1_{A}+1_{B}\right) (\omega)$$
Both of these functions have values in $\{0,1,2\}$. Now you have 4 cases 
$\omega \in A\setminus B, B\setminus A, A\cap B$ and $(A\cup B)^c$.

Now you have $$ \left(1_{A\cup B}+1_{A\cap B}\right)(\omega)\begin{cases}
0, \quad \omega\notin A\cup B,\\
1,\quad \omega \in A\triangle B,\\
2, \quad \omega \in A\cap B.
\end{cases}$$

You can now see how the left and right had sides of 
$$\left(1_{A\cup B}+1_{A\cap B}\right)(\omega)=1_{A}+1_{B} (\omega)$$
are the same in all cases.